# Is there an optimal way to write dynamic component switching in React?

Tags: dynamic, ecmascript-6, reactjs

When writing components for a layout that needs to be switched dynamically via data from the backend, I often find myself writing React components that look like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import DateInput from './DateInput';

const Input = (props) => {
    const {
        type,
        ...otherProps
    } = props;
    switch (type) {
        case 'text':
            return <TextInput {...otherProps} />;
        case 'date':
            return <DateInput {...otherProps} />;
        // etc…
        default:
            return null;
    }
};

export default Input;
```

Which leads to the list of imports ballooning when the types are expanded upon.

Is there any alternative method for dynamic component switching that would be more optimal/performant/reliable than this one?

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
import React from 'react';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import DateInput from './DateInput';

const TYPES = {
  text: TextInput,
  date: DateInput,
};

const Input = (props) => {
    const {
        type,
        ...otherProps
    } = props;
    const Component = TYPES[type];
    if (!Component) return null;

    return <Component {...otherProps} />;
};

export default Input;
```

Generally you want to enumerate the possible options somewhere, and an object lookup is an easy way to do it. Dynamic `require` calls that other answers have mentioned are generally a little questionable because tools cannot analyse the dependencies, and it means you're API is much harder to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can use require to dynamically load modules. However you have to define somewhere what is the component module path. For example:

```
const components = {
  text: 'TextInput',
  date: 'DateInput',
};

const Input = (props) => {
    const { type, ...otherProps } = props;
    const Component = require('./' + components[type]);
    return type ? <Component {...otherProps} /> : null;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a build tool such as webpack dynamic requires are supported, which allows you to do something like the following:

```
import React from 'react';

const typeMap = {
  text: 'TextInput',
  date: 'DateInput'
};

const Input = (props) => {
    const {
        type,
        ...otherProps
    } = props;

    const typeInput = typeMap[type];

    if (!typeInput) return null;

    const InputComponent = require(`./${typeInput}`);

    return <InputComponent { ...otherProps } />;
};

export default Input;
```